# Trying to draw an arc using Java

Tags: java, swing

i've been trying to draw an arc in java using this code:

```
g.fillArc(50, 50, 100, 100, 0, 180)
```

where g is a graphics object.

which yields the blue object below:

[image: result]

what i'm actually trying to do is produce something that looks like this:

[image: striving for]

thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4):

Try `g.fillArc(50, 50, 100, 100, 180, 180)` instead.

Basically, the first angle is the where to start, the second angle is the number of degrees (from the start) it should arc through.

So if you just wanted a pie slip of 5 degrees, you would use something like `g.fillArc(50, 50, 100, 100, 0, 5)`

Have a look at [`Graphics#fillArc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillArc%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) for more info

**Working example**

[image]

```
public class PaintTest03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PaintTest03();
    }

    public PaintTest03() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new PaintPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class PaintPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillArc(0, 0, 100, 100, 180, 180);        
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Even `g.fillArc(50, 50, 100, 100, 0, -180)` should be fine.

Comment: hmm that first line up there seems to be yielding no results, in that it doesn't produce any visible object whatsoever.

Comment: Make sure the component your are painting on is sized correctly, as the are is drawing at 50x50

Comment: You might also try using an `AffineTransform` (or rather, a concatenation of 3 `AffineTransform` instances) that flips all rendering upside down.